# Junit4 giving "no tests found" when running junit on simple test cases

Tags: command-line, java

I need some help getting junit4 working on ubuntu 14.04. I have installed junit correctly (I hope!), when I use `junit -v` in the terminal it returns junit 4.11. However when I compile with javac: `javac TestCase.java` and the run `junit TestCase` it returns no tests found.

My simple test code is:

```
   import static org.junit.Assert.*;
   import org.junit.Before;
   import org.junit.Test;

   public class ClubMemberTest{

        @Test
        public void test1(){
            assertTrue(1-1==0);
        }

    }
```

I have put junit4.jar and junit4-4.11.jar in my CLASSPATH variable using the .bashrc file.

I'm still pretty new to linux & ubuntu so any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Your class `ClubMemberTest` have to extend `junit.framework.TestCase`

```
import org.junit.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ClubMemberTest extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public static void test1() {
        assertTrue(1 - 1 == 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been searching for hours for an answer to this!